# Is it possible when registering a user via firebase and react to collect his first name, last name, phone number and address?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I use the updateProfile function, but it seems to only collect first name and photo

```
import firebaseConfig from "../firebaseConfig";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const Singup = () => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  let [name, setName] = useState("");
  let [secondName, setSecondName] = useState("");
  let [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  let [index, setIndex] = useState("");
  let [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  let [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  let [err, setErr] = useState("");
  let handleSubmit = () => {
    if (!name && !secondName && !phone && !index && !email && !password) {
      setErr("Fill the all details!");
    } else if (!name) {
      setErr("Enter your name!");
    } else if (!secondName) {
      setErr("Enter your second name!");
    } else if (!phone) {
      setErr("Enter your phone!");
    } else if (!index) {
      setErr("Enter your index!");
    } else if (!email) {
      setErr("Enter your email!");
    } else if (!password) {
      setErr("Enter your password!");
    } else if (password.length < 6) {
      setErr("Password need minimum 6 character!");
    } else {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in
          updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
            displayName: name,
            displaySecondName: secondName,
            displayPhone: phone,
            displayIndex: index,
          }).then(() => {
            // Profile updated!
            setErr("");
            navigate("/");
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.code);
          if (error.code == "auth/email-already-in-use") {
            setErr("Email already in use!");
          } else {
            setErr("");
          }
        });
    }
  };
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  })
```

Comment: Please provide your function for further clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a user schema defined and exported as a model somewhere in your project directory. Make sure that it contains all the required fields. Then, in your `updateProfile` function, you can access and change any property that you want.

Also, provide the code for your function as it helps in understanding the question better.

Comment: Updated* 

Can you share any tutorials, please?